# How to create a color aura around actors in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

Is there an easy mechanism to create a color aura around an actor in libGDX?

Thanks for all tips!

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better/more efficient way to do it, but an easy way would be to draw a tinted, mostly transparent circle on top of an actor. (Or beneath the actor if you don't want the actor itself tinted.)

If you have a white circle texture and want a red aura, then the draw code would look like this

```
Color oldColor = batch.getColor();
batch.setColor(1,0,0,.2f);
batch.draw(circleTexture,x,y,width,height);
batch.setColor(oldColor);
```